# Finding the "a" string in file within a block for one time using python

Tags: python

I have a file contains 3 blocks 
Block1:
a
Block2:
a
Block3:
a 
I wanted to search "block1:" a string using python 
I have done code for Searching block1 : and a string but it is giving all the a

```
file = open( "c:\Textfile.txt", "r" ).readlines()
var=raw_input("enter the value")
var1="// Block1:"
for line in file:
    if re.search(var1,line,re.IGNORECASE):
        print re.search(var,line,re.IGNORECASE)
        print "found",line
        for line in file:
            if re.search(var,line,re.IGNORECASE):
                print "value=",line
```

Comment: It would be useful if you show the contents of 1.txt as well as an example of the desired output.

Comment: 1.txt contains Block1: a b Block2: a c Block3: a d I want output is Block1: a element

Comment: You have to supply the precise contents of 1.txt in the question field above (you can edit it) formatted the same way the code is. when you say that your 1.txt contains Block1: a b Block2: a c Block3: a then this is probably misleading, as the file probably places that on 3 lines not 1 but we cannot see that from your answer.

Comment: ok, How can I get "a" element from the Block1: not block2 and Block3

Comment: can you give a sample format of your Textfile.txt file,then it will be easier for us to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you Textfile is like below:

```
    Block1: test is t
    Block2: test is u
    Block3: test is V
```

You can do it like below:

```
import re
file = open( "Textfile.txt", "r" ).readlines()
var=raw_input("enter the value")
for line in file:
    if line.find('Block1:') != -1:
        if re.search(var,line,re.IGNORECASE):
            print "value=",line
```

Comment: Code is working 

Block1: 
test is t
Block2: 
test is t
Block3: 
test is t  

if "t" is in new line what have to do in code

Comment: if text file contains "Block1: test is t Block2: test is t Block3: test is t" then code will be :                                  import re
file = open("Textfile.txt", 'r+')
data = file.read()
var=raw_input("enter the value") 
block1 =  data.split('Block2')[0]
if re.search(var,block1,re.IGNORECASE):
 print block1.split(':')[1]

Comment: `line.find('Block1:') != -1:` could be `if 'Block1: ' in line:` for better readability.